# SQL INNER JOIN return null result

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I want to get data from two tables. for that i used inner join for joining. first table have all the details what i want and second table has details more than that data.

After querying data i get null data for second table values.

```
SELECT * FROM 
          facility_costdel as fc 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN 
          basic_facility_del as bf
          on fc.facility_code = bf.facility_code
```

Is there any wrong with my query?

Comment: try SELECT * FROM 
          facility_costdel as fc 
          JOIN 
          basic_facility_del as bf
          on fc.facility_code = bf.facility_code

Comment: is there any common facility code in two tables?

Comment: yes there are so many common facility codes

Comment: facility code is number or varchar?? also which dbms..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78586/discussion-between-tpfd-and-sachu).

Comment: Make sure that they both have the same data type. If they do, then try to trim white spaces on the joining condition from both columns

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying correct..if any matching data is there it should return rows.
Then there is three possibility for returning no results

```
1. There is no matching facility_code between two tables.
2. If matching facility_code is there then match case can be different..
   (lower case and upper case)
3. Third case is leading or trailing spaces.
```

I guess you are using sql server..Try below code

```
SELECT * FROM 
          facility_costdel as fc 
          JOIN 
          basic_facility_del as bf
          on ltrim(rtrim(fc.facility_code)) = ltrim(rtrim(bf.facility_code))
```